# Rails 5 - Iterating over part of an array for the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently use EasyAutoComplete for a search form. If you hit 'View All' it redirects to the same page but with params[:name] to show all cards.

I render this with:

```
<% @cards.in_groups_of(6, false).each do |group| %>
      <div class='row'>
        <% group.each do |card| %>
          <div class='col-sm-2 col-md-2'>
            <div class="wrapperImg">
              <%= link_to image_tag(card.image_url, class: "img-responsive"), {:controller => "cards", :action => "show", :id => card.id }%>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

However, if you look up a specific set of cards it's going to return a couple hundred (or more) of essentially the same card. I can identify these cards by a parameter(rarity)

I was originally going to try to modify it in the controller, but that is an issue because the 'def index' makes the EasyAutoComplete work

```
  def index
    wild_search = "%#{params[:name]}%"
    @cards = Card.order(multiverse_id: :desc).limit(30)
    # debugger
    #@cards =  @cards.where("name like :name", name: wild_search).page(params[:page]) if params[:name]
    @cards = @cards.where("name like :name OR setName like :name", name: wild_search).page(params[:page]) if params[:name]
  end
```

Is there a way for me to do something like

`cards = @cards.where('rarity IS NOT ?', 'Land')` or something similar in the view, then modify my output from `@cards.in_group_of` to `cards.in_group_of`? Or is there a way to use the Controller to do this and use `def search` instead of `def index`?

Welcome any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
<% @cards.where.not(rarity: "Land").in_groups_of(6, false).each do |group| %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't think I could chain where like that. Thanks!
I'll accept the answer - But it's a daisy chain issue. Correct version would be
`<% @cards.where.not(rarity: "Basic Land").in_groups_of(6, false).each do |group| %>`